# Dart server response HTML from string

Tags: html, http, dart, server

I have the below code which is based on an example from the Dart docs, using an HTML snippet from the HTML wikipedia page. The browser renders this as a string, how can I get the browser to render it as HTML? I've been through all the dart docs and examples and can't find anything, and also tried different content headers with no luck.

```dart
final server = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4, 8000);
await for (HttpRequest request in server) {
  request.response.write("""<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>This is a title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
      <p>Hello world!</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>""");
  await request.response.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the content type:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> main() async {
  final server = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4, 8000);
  await for (HttpRequest request in server) {
    request.response.headers.contentType = ContentType.html;
    request.response.write("""<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>This is a title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
      <p>Hello world!</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>""");
    await request.response.close();
  }
}
```